# Automatically inserting "-" or "/" character for MM-YYYY textfields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a CC Validation template at the moment, but using the standard dropdown/separate textfields for selecting the Month/Year expiration fields is unfortunately not on the cards for this particular project.

Instead, I'm looking to have one textfield (in the format MM-YYYY) for capturing the expiration date - however, I'm looking to write this so that a customer is not required to enter the "-" or "/" between the Month/Year entries.

Instead, after the customer types in say, "02", the hyphen or slash should automatically appear after it. If the customer then backspaces over the year, the hyphen/slash should also be removed, allowing for them to easily edit their month data.

Are there any decent solutions available which accomplish this? Or is it a case of rolling your own?

Comment: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

Comment: Why don't you have two textboxes, and merge them with CSS?

Comment: I'd recommend rolling your own.  I've done something similar in the past and it isn't that tough.  It is actually a great exercise for this kind of thing.  Here is a page to get you started https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this, I created for date
https://jsfiddle.net/dhruv1992/6fk8fb1v/

```
<input type="text" id="dateofbirth">
```

jquery

```
$("#dateofbirth").on('keyup',function(event){
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    if (key == 8 || key == 46) return false;
    var strokes = $(this).val().length;
    if(strokes === 2 || strokes === 5){
        var thisVal = $(this).val();
        thisVal += '/';
        $(this).val(thisVal);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do `8` and `46` represent? I know, but would the next programmer know? Why use `$(this).val().length` when `this.value.length` is hundreds of times faster? In fact you're creating `$(this)` three times when you can just do `this.value += "/";` but besides that, what if I want to backspace? I can't because you blocked `keyCode 8`. Basically what I'm saying is, this is extremely unfriendly both to programmers and to users, which is quite an achievement really...

Comment: I just did to make my code more clear. sorry but I don't prefer shortcuts.

Comment: Your code is not clear. At all. Not to programmers, and not to the browser either as it has to do unnecessary calculations for no reason at all...

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty crude (but does at least implement your requirements).

https://jsfiddle.net/justinwyllie/ntdwc1qt/

```
$('#cc').on('input', function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    if (v.length == 2) {
        $(this).val(v + '-');   
    }

   if (v.length == 3) {
        $(this).val(v.substring(0,2));  
    }


})
```

Maybe a combination of this and dhruv gupta's answer which at least tries to detect the keystrokes?

Comment: btw input may not be ideal as it does not fire on the backspace - according to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: Re your comment: that is only true for IE9, as per the link you provided. Seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="month" />
```

Job done.

Comment: What browser is this working in, @Niet? I can't get this to work in Firefox 51.

Comment: @Rounin [Basically everything except Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) because Firefox is the new IE.

Comment: Haha. Ouch.  I like FF for the same reason that I like Chromium ;-) And I see from caniuse that FF54 does / will support. Thanks for the right caniuse page (I searched, but not for _datetime_).

Answer (score 0):

I liked *@31piy*'s idea of having two text boxes.

Here is one approach using two text input boxes:

```js
var inputMonth =  document.querySelector('input[placeholder="mm"]');
var inputYear = document.querySelector('input[placeholder="yyyy"]');
var enteredDate = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

function updateEnteredDate() {

    enteredDate.textContent = '';

    if (inputMonth.value.length > 0) {
     enteredDate.textContent += inputMonth.value;
    }


    if ((inputMonth.value.length > 1) && (inputYear.value.length < 1)) {

     if (document.activeElement === inputMonth) {
         enteredDate.textContent += '-';
         inputYear.focus();
     }

     else if (document.activeElement === inputYear) {
         inputMonth.focus();
     }
    }

    if (inputYear.value.length > 0) {
     enteredDate.textContent += '-';
     enteredDate.textContent += inputYear.value;
    }

}

inputMonth.addEventListener('keyup', updateEnteredDate, false);
inputYear.addEventListener('keyup', updateEnteredDate, false);
window.addEventListener('load', function(){inputMonth.focus();}, false)
```

```css
p {
height: 72px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 72px;
font-size: 72px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p></p>

<form>
<input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" placeholder="mm" />
<input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder="yyyy" />
</form>
```