# How to auto insert/add colon (:) after every 2 character in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to auto insert a colon (`:`) after every 2 character in my input:

***HTML***

```html
<input nz-input type="text" appLimitInput="textAndNumbers" name="mac" 
  formControlName="mac" (keydown.space)="$event.preventDefault();"
  onDrag="return false;" onDrop="return false;" onPaste="return false;">
```

**Desired affect:**

When I try to input `AB` then it will automatically add colon then when I type another text which is `CD`

then It will be like this `AB:CD` then when I try to delete/erase the `CD` then It will auto delete/erase the colon.

`AB:CD:EF:GH:IJ:KL`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically inserting "-" or "/" character for MM-YYYY textfields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858073/automatically-inserting-or-character-for-mm-yyyy-textfields)

Answer (score 6):

You can add an [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) to your input element that triggers a component method that will reformat it's value as follows:

**Template:**

```html
<input (input)="reformat($event) />
```

**Component:**

```js
reformat(event) {
  if (event.data) { // We don't want it to trigger on delete so we make sure there is data in the event (the entered char)
    const two_chars_no_colons_regex = /([^:]{2}(?!:))/g;
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(two_chars_no_colons_regex, "$1:");
  }
}
```

**Regex explanation:**
`/../g` Javascript regex literal syntax with global flag which matches all occurrences of the regex
`()` - A selection group we will reference later as $1
`[^:]` - Every char except colons
`{2}` - Preceding expression should come twice
`(?!:)` - Preceding expressions should not have colons after it \

[Here is a working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ig59ex?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This doesn't work If user pastes a text longer than2 characters. It will not make change to that.